# PyMongo counting number of elements by date

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregate-functions

I have DB with my users:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a0decadefcb09087c08a868"
    },
    "user_id": "5b232a5a-b333-4320-ba63-722b9e167ef3",
    "email": "email@email.com",
    "password": "***",
    "registration_date": {
        "$date": "2017-11-16T19:53:17.946Z"
    },
    "type": "user"
},

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5a0ded3aefcb090887d7f4fb"
    },
    "user_id": "0054bbde-3ba0-490f-8d54-ffaf72958888",
    "email": "second@gmail.com",
    "password": "***",
    "registration_date": {
        "$date": "2017-11-16T19:55:38.194Z"
    },
    "type": "user"
}
```

I want to count users by each date (registration_date) and get some thing like that:

```
01.01.2017 – 10
01.02.2017 – 20
01.03.2017 – 15
...
```

I'm trying that code, but it doesn't work:

```
def registrations_by_date(self):
    users = self.users_db.aggregate([
        {'$group': {
            '_id': {'registration_date':'$date'},
            'count': {'$sum':1}
        }},
    ])
    return users
```

What i'm doing wrong? How to get this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the date in your schema is of ISODate

then the below aggregate query will work, the date format is done before grouping so that the timestamp is not taken while grouping the data

```
{
        "_id" : "5a0decadefcb09087c08a868",
        "user_id" : "5b232a5a-b333-4320-ba63-722b9e167ef3",
        "email" : "email@email.com",
        "password" : "***",
        "registration_date" : ISODate("2017-11-16T19:53:17.946Z"),
        "type" : "user"
}
{
        "_id" : "5a0ded3aefcb090887d7f4fb",
        "user_id" : "0054bbde-3ba0-490f-8d54-ffaf72958888",
        "email" : "second@gmail.com",
        "password" : "***",
        "registration_date" : ISODate("2017-11-16T19:55:38.194Z"),
        "type" : "user"
}
```

The aggregation query to get the result is

```
db.userReg.aggregate([
  {$project: 
    { formattedRegDate:
      { "$dateToString": {format:"%Y-%m-%d", date:"$registration_date"}}
    }
  },
  {$group:{_id:"$formattedRegDate", count:{$sum:1}}}]);
```

and the result is

```
{ "_id" : "2017-11-16", "count" : 2 }
```

> If the date in your schema is of String

then the below approach to be used

Sample Data

```
{
        "_id" : "5a0decadefcb09087c08a868",
        "user_id" : "5b232a5a-b333-4320-ba63-722b9e167ef3",
        "email" : "email@email.com",
        "password" : "***",
        "registration_date" : "2017-11-16T19:53:17.946Z",
        "type" : "user"
}
{
        "_id" : "5a0ded3aefcb090887d7f4fb",
        "user_id" : "0054bbde-3ba0-490f-8d54-ffaf72958888",
        "email" : "second@gmail.com",
        "password" : "***",
        "registration_date" : "2017-11-16T19:55:38.194Z",
        "type" : "user"
}
```

Query

```
db.userReg.aggregate([{
   $group:{ _id: { date: {"$substr":["$registration_date", 0, 10]}},
     count:{$sum:1}
   }
}]);
```

and the result is

```
{ "_id" : { "date" : "2017-11-16" }, "count" : 2 }
```

Comment: One problem it sorts not by day increasing, "date": "2017-11-27"
"date": "2017-11-21"
"date": "2017-11-20"
"date": "2017-11-26"

Comment: Use $sort of aggregation pipeline for the date field, `{$sort: {date:1}}` for ascending order and `{$sort: {date:-1}}` for descending order

Comment: Returned same order anyway (-1 or 1 no difference) – https://yadi.sk/i/psVHEIZD3QBVAT

Comment: Fix it on Python side. Thanks again !

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have an extra **,**

```
db.userReg.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: "$registration_date", count: {$sum:1}}}
])
```

This gives the correct result(**ON the basis of record on my mcahine**) :

> {
>       "_id" : ISODate("2017-11-15T19:55:38.194Z"),
>       "count" : 1.0 }
>
> {
>       "_id" : ISODate("2017-11-16T19:55:38.194Z"),
>       "count" : 2.0 }